# swift: how do I change the font to Courier in a mail-text?

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, swift5

I would like to send a text with a pseudo table (columns filled with spaces) as a mail. But it looks terrible with the standard font - all lines are of different lengths. When I look at the text in the debugger, it looks good: all lines are 80 characters long. How do I use 'attributedString'? Or how do I change the font to 'Courier' so that all lines look the same length?
In a text view, the "Courier" font is fine.

```
        let picker = MFMailComposeViewController()
        picker.mailComposeDelegate = self

        if let subjectText = self.subject {
            picker.setSubject(subjectText)
        }
        picker.setMessageBody(self.body     , isHTML: false)

        self.present(picker, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

who can help me? Who knows how to change the font for the mail?
Thanks in advance to anyone who can help.

Comment: Se the `isHTML` to `true` and embed `self.body` into a HTML tag where you set the font to Courier. Like: `picker.setMessageBody("<p style=\"font-family:'Courier New\'">\(self.body)</p>", isHTML: true)`
`